# ps + kworker with state D

Tags: redhat, process, kernel, ps

we have redhat machines in cluster

redhat version is - 7.2

when we perform

```
ps ax
```

on the machine we saw many kworker with state D

example

```
17165  ?  D  0:00  [kworker/u66:1]
2151  ?  D  0:58  [kworker/u33:0]
3866  ?  D  0:26  [kworker/u65:0]
14967  ?  D  0:00  [kworker/2:1]
2014  ?  D  0:10  [kworker/u65:1]
19021  ?  D  0:05  [kworker/u65:0]
26880  ?  D  9:43  [kworker/16:2]
7972  ?  D  9:04  [kworker/31:1]
12295  ?  D  2:01  [kworker/3:1]
13859  ?  D  0:11  [kworker/u65:3]
```

I must to say that we also face high load average on the CPU

based on that information , what should be the conclusion?

for example what we need to verify ? or to perform some tune for the OS?

Comment: The first thing you should think when you see `D` in `ps` output is **disk**.

Comment: yes I am also thinking about this , but i see that iowait is normal , or maybe you have suggestions ?

Comment: We have no way to know if it is normal. We don't know what your workload is.

Comment: we saw also many on the machine we saw many kswapd0 with state D

example

134  ?  D  1099:58  [kswapd0]
134  ?  D  1150:21  [kswapd0]
134  ?  D  1099:59  [kswapd0]
134  ?  D  1150:21  [kswapd0]
134  ?  D  928:00  [kswapd0]
134  ?  D  1099:59  [kswapd0]
134  ?  D  1150:22  [kswapd0]

Comment: What is the user response time problem? Not the load average, but what are users complaining about that is slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a kworker in d status and you are running other processes with i/o and the process is also in d status, chances are you can not kill either.

A reboot is required.